# writeln() messes with Pascal output

Tags: pascal

On a computer science lesson, I was tasked to write a simple piece of code. Program receives a sequence of integers, and it should output the length of the longest same-integer sequence. It also stops after reading two zeros.
[image: input and output]

Here is the code:

```
type int64array = array[1..10000] of int64;
var n,x,counting,buffer:int64;
var nlist:int64array;
function counter(list:int64array): int64;
    var i,j,a,b:int64;
    begin
        for i:=1 to 10000 do 
            begin
                if list[i]=0 then Break;
                a:=1;
                for j:=i+1 to 10000 do
                    begin
                        if ((list[i]=list[j]) and (list[i]=list[j-1])) then a:=a+1;
                    end;
                if a>b then b:=a;
            end;
    counter:=b;
    end;
begin
n:=1;
buffer:=1;
while True do
    begin
        readln(n);
        x:=counter(nlist);
        if ((n=0) and (buffer=0)) then Break;
        counting:=counting+1;
        nlist[counting]:=n;
        buffer:=n;
        writeln()
    end;
writeln(x);
end.
```

It produces the wanted result and works correctly, but creates unnecessary empty lines.

Losing the `writeln()` in line 30 messes with output and the program produces rubbish numbers.

Here's the input for both programs:

```
1
1
0
0
```

The output with the `writeln()` line:

```
2
```

The output without it:

```
140735786777216
```

The end goal is to create a program that works correctly, but doesn't produce empty lines.

Comment: It works exactly as it should. The question you _ought_ be asking yourself is "how is my loop wrongly printing so many blank lines?"

Comment: @Dúthomhas, I think you missed the point. It doesn't work as it should, and I know why the loop prints blank lines. I need a program that does work, but doesn't produce blank lines. I've edited my question to make myself more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output with the `writeln()` line: […] The output without it: […]

I’m sorry to break it to you, pal, but the problem is you must be using a broke processor.
This is indeed a change in code that should *not* affect the remainder of your program’s behavior.

> The end goal is to create a program that works correctly, but doesn't produce empty lines.

The best solution is to switch to [a processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#Pascal_compilers) that ain’t broke.
The worst solution is, of course, addressing your processor’s bugs, yet it can also improve your program’s design.
In particular, your algorithm should *by design* not read *uninitialized* data.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid switching to another processor, I just simplified the code.
And now it works correctly:

```
var n,buffer,counter,maxval,repeats:int64;
begin
buffer:=-1001;
while True do
    begin
        readln(n);
        if ((n=0) and (buffer=0)) then Break;
        if n=buffer then inc(counter)
        else counter:=1;
        if counter>maxval then maxval:=counter;
        buffer:=n;
        inc(repeats);
    end;
if repeats=1 then writeln(0)
else writeln(maxval);
end.
```